# Server Side Rendering: You are not authorized to perform this action

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

I tried implementing Server Side Rendering with Spartacus's provided documentation
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/
Spartacus v2.1.0
Angular v9.1.12

But every time I refresh the page the page I get served initialy shows the error message :You are not authorized to perform this action. with nothing else below the header. After a second or so the page hydrates and the right content is displayed. My expected behaviour would be that the page served represents the page after hydration. Seeing the issue only on the initial load makes me believe there is something not configured properly when the SSR was set up some time ago. I'd be happy to supply code snippets when needed.

This behaviour happens on every page, currently having tried it as a guest to the website (Not Logged in).

I've tried to find similar issues but have only found this as a reference: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/2390 which doesn't align with our current use case as far as I can tell.

Comment: There were a few patches to this version. Please upgrade and check in version 2.1.6 and let us know.

Comment: Did you end up fixing the issue?